# Using a specific part of string for an array [python]

Tags: python, arrays, list, substring

I have a text list of strings:

**3814-F76A-2451** -54 -59.1 61 4.03051 -0.0595874 Feb-27 13:33:23.044623
**3014-F56A-2454** -73 -60 -63 127 4.40527 0.828709 Feb-27 13:32:01.692607
**3414-F76A-2451** -65 -51 -53.4 13 4.36092 -0.895371 Feb-27 13:34:26.504497

I want to create an array out of **these** substrings (hex), the first entry to be **3814F76A2451**, the second **3014F56A2454** and so on.

Thank you for your time in advance !

Comment: Will the substring always have the same length?

Comment: If the size is always the same: "3814-F76A-2451 -54 -59.1 61 4.03051 -0.0595874 Feb-27 13:33:23.044623"[:14]

Comment: @Guy yes the substring will always have the same length!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the substrings are always 14 characters you can take them from each string

```
strings = ['3814-F76A-2451 -54 -59.1 61 4.03051 -0.0595874 Feb-27 13:33:23.044623',
           '3014-F56A-2454 -73 -60 -63 127 4.40527 0.828709 Feb-27 13:32:01.692607',
           '3414-F76A-2451 -65 -51 -53.4 13 4.36092 -0.895371 Feb-27 13:34:26.504497']

substrings = [s[:14].replace('-', '') for s in strings]
```

If the length can change split each string by whitespace and take the first result

```
substrings = [s.split(' ')[0].replace('-', '') for s in strings]
```

Output

```
# ['3814F76A2451', '3014F56A2454', '3414F76A2451']
```

**Edit**:

To answer the comment if the strings are part of a long text you can get all the substrings from it that match `xxxx-xxxx-xxxx` format

```
text = '3814-F76A-2451 3814sF76A-2451 -54 -59.1 61 4.03051 -0.0595874 Feb-27 13:33:23.044623 3014-F56A-2454 -73 -60 -63 127 4.40527 0.828709 Feb-27 13:32:01.692607 3414-F76A-2451 -65 -51 -53.4 13 4.36092 -0.895371 Feb-27 13:34:26.504497'
strings = [t[:14].replace('-', '') for t in text.split(' ') if re.match('^[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}', t)]
```

Comment: Thats already very helpful, but i got a long list and i dont want to seperate them manually, how can i do this?

Comment: also, i want the hyphen to dissappear, so i can use it as a 12-digit hex number. Can i do this in the same step?

Comment: @eranduscohortae What do you mean? aren't the strings already in a list of strings? see edited answer for removing `-`.

Comment: unfortunatly not, they are a mess and all over the place, its a very long single string :/

Answer (score 1):

Well, with the **modified** terms as per OP's comment, probably the best solution is to use regexp. Assuming the substrings to be found always consist of three groups separated with dashes, four hex digits each:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}')
substrings = [ x.replace('-', '') for x in re.findall(pattern, a_very_long_single_string) ]
```